# IPhone App to IPad App How to make transition from ViewController.xib to ViewController-iPad.xib ?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad

I am using XCode 4.0.

I am Transiting from my iPhone App to IPad as a universal app?

I have some doubts for xib files?

Should I use the autoresize element for each UIElement?

Or

```
Trasit each xib file to the ipad xib file?
How? Could not get the option for that?
```

.

Answer (score 1):

Use different .xib files for iPad and iPhone and `initWithNibName:bundle:`. Determine whether to use one or another using this block

```
NSString *nibName = nil;
if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
  nibName = @"CustomViewControllerIpad";
}
else {
  nibName = @"CustomViewControllerIphone";
}

CustomViewController *viewController = [[CustomViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nibName bundle[NSBundle mainBundle]];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
[viewController release];
```